# Would optical signal processing still suffer from slew rate?

Tags: optics

In electronics, analog signal processing/computation suffers from parasitic capacitance which leads to [slew rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slew_rate)—which is the maximum rate of voltage change allowed, so handling super-high frequency becomes impossible.

Is this still true for optical signal processing/computation, such as optical (frequency) mixer or optical frequency multiplier? If so, what would be the physics behind?

Comment: You might want to ask this question on [Physics.SE](http://physics.stackexchange.com/)...

Comment: You still need to *convert* between optical end electrical and *there* lies the problem.

Comment: Isn't light an electro-magnetic wave? Speed of light (in material) is still affected by dielectric material E0 and magnetic permeability mu0. So there is still an equivalent slew rate.

Comment: @MarkU I don't think that slew rate and propagation speed are directly related.

Comment: @hannobinder True, slew rate and propagation speed are different effects, but slew rate *is* directly related to capacitance. I don't see how light could avoid the dielectric material's effect on the wave's electric field.

Comment: Perhaps the answer is in the difference between a beam of light and an electric current - one is a wave with transverse E-H fields, and the other is more like a pressure wave propagating through a cloud of electrons. I still can't help thinking there's no free lunch, but I'm not sure how to prove it in this case.

Comment: I think I got one more point: For electrons to propagate a wave, the electrons have to move back and forth, i.e. they need to be accelerated and decelerated continuously. Accelerated charges dissipate some of their kinetic energy as e-m radiation. Now light (photons) are not charged, and they are not accelerated/decelerated during transmission, and they don't radiate anything while they are not accelerated. Hence I doubt that induction and capacitance can be transferred to light in a sensible way. That's why I'd say there's no slew for light. Except maybe for the wavelength as limiting factor.

Answer (score 1):

Your question includes both the *conversion* (since you speak of *processing*) and light propagation. Conversion involves electronics, as @Nasha mentions, and thus *is* directly impacted by the slew rate.

Light propagation speed is reduced (with respect to that in vacuum) by the refractive index of the material. The physics causing the finite slew rate is also also causing the fact that the refractive index of the material is always greater than 1.